# How to send form inputs to email using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

on submit, i would like for the contents of this form to be sent to an email address, I am unsure of what to add to the function below for it to work effectively.

HTML

```
          <div class="form-container" id="form-container">
                        <h2>Get a quote</h2>
                        <form id="contact" autocomplete="off" action="#">
                            <div class="form-field name-field">
                                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                                <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                                <div class="error"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="comment" placeholder="Your Message" form="usrform"></textarea>
                                <div class="error text"></div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="submit">Send Message</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-container2 hide" id="form-container2">
                        <img src="assets/success.svg" alt="">
                        <h3>Message Sent</h3>
                        <p>Thanks for reaching out, our team will get back to you in the next 48 hours</p>
                        <button id="back" onclick="refreshPage()">Go Back</button>
                    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        field(user, 0, "Name cannot be blank");
        field(msg, 2, "Message cannot be blank");

        if (
            !user.classList.contains("invalid") &&
            !email.classList.contains("invalid") &&
            !msg.classList.contains("invalid")
        ) {
            location.href = form.getAttribute("action");
            container1.classList.add("hide");
            container2.classList.remove("hide");
        }

       

});
```

Comment: I will advice you to send the form through PHP, after it has been validated. You can use fetch command from js to handle the data to the PHP file.

Comment: @NicolasTome I have no clue how to begin this, would you mind showing me?